# 'history' PropType is defined but prop is never usedeslint(react/no-unused-prop-types) what is the eslint error embedded with this line of Code?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

```
Reset.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any).isRequired,
};
```

it throws an eslint error that "'history' PropType is defined but prop is never used eslint(react/no-unused-prop-types)".How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the property is actually being used in your component
- If it isn't, remove the propType

You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unused-prop-types.md)